# Getting "StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException" while running tests with runsettings

Tags: selenium, mstest, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache, vstest.console.exe

I am facing an issue while trying to run the test using runsettings file.
We have one redis cache with SSL enabled which we are trying to access from our tests.

***StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: SET sample.TM.test|ConnectionSample|System.String|Sample ---> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on .cache.windows.net:6380/Subscription, origin: Connected, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 1s ago, last-write: 1s ago, unanswered-write: 464270s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: Connecting, last-heartbeat: never, last-mbeat: -1s ago, global: 1s ago, mgr: Inactive, err: never ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host***

When are able to run the same tests **without** using this runsettings.

Is there anyway I can successfully run the tests without migrating to MSTest V2?

OR

Can I use the same Test Controller/Agent setup with MSTest V2 for running tests?

Comment: Please see the runsettings file that I am using.

**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
    <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
    <ResultsDirectory>..\Portal\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <MSTest>
    <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>
    <CaptureTraceOutput>false</CaptureTraceOutput>
    <SettingsFile>Local.testsettings</SettingsFile>
    <ForcedLegacyMode>true</ForcedLegacyMode>
  </MSTest>
</RunSettings>**

Comment: Can other programs connect to and use your redis cache service normally?

Comment: @JasonPan Yes. The tests itself is running (is able to connect to redis) if I am not specifying the .runsettings. The issue happens only when we are providing the runsettings file and tries to execute the tests.
As per the analysis, what I found is "<ForcedLegacyMode>" tag is making some changes to the way the test is trying to access the redis. 

I couldn't find what exactly is the difference when we specify the <ForcedLegacyMode> as true in runsettings file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding following keys to the registry of my test agent machines.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001